# Configuring maxKeepAliveRequests in Spring Boot embedded Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot

I need to modify the maxKeepAliveRequests value in my Spring Boot Zuul gateway to a value higher than the default 100. Noting that this value is not exposed in Spring Boot's [common properties list](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html), I tried to set the property via @Configuration class instead:

```java
@Configuration
public class DefaultConfig {
    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainerFactory() {
        TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();

        factory.addConnectorCustomizers(connector ->
                ((AbstractHttp11Protocol) connector.getProtocolHandler()).setMaxKeepAliveRequests(1000));

        return factory;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't seem to take the desired effect. Is there a proper way for me to change Tomcat properties that are not exposed via Spring common properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code above has been confirmed to work. It was a silly mistake with a wrong @ComponentScan scope that caused my code not to work.