# Spring external client timeout

Tags: java, spring, restclientbuilder

In our Spring Application we rely on an external system.
We want to set a timeout on the requests to that system, but can't figure out how to configure this.

We use this:

```
   return clientBuilder.build()
            .target(baseUrl)
            .register(jsonProvider)
            .register(jsonAcceptHeaderClientRequestFilter)
            .register(new LoggingFilter());
```

I've tried this:
[How to set the connection and read timeout with Jersey 2.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19543209/how-to-set-the-connection-and-read-timeout-with-jersey-2-x) and many other suggestions, but can't get it to work. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Update of things that do not work:

```
.property("http.connection.timeout", 1)
.property("http.receive.timeout", 1)
```

As well as

```
.property(ClientProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT,1)
.property(ClientProperties.READ_TIMEOUT,1)
```

Comment: Does it have to be specific to the request for the `external system`? I know that you can configure the request timeout globally by using the `server.connection-timeout` property. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44274982/spring-boot-application-what-is-default-timeout-for-any-rest-api-endpoint-or-a

Comment: Will that effect timeouts of requests made to our system as well?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately. I don't know any way to set a timeout by request because it seems like it's managed by the embedded server (Tomcat), but there may be an alternative elsewhere

Comment: Hmmm, as recommended on that Jersey timeout link, trying either `target(baseUrl).property(ClientProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 1)` or `target(baseUrl).property(ClientProperties.READ_TIMEOUT, 1)` both cause a `javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException` failure locally.  It seems unlikely you haven't tried that though - it feels like there is something more going on than the sample above?  (This was with jersey-client-2.14)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As confirmed in the answer linked in your question, one of the comments by @df778899 and as per my tests, the below usage works alright, for [jersey](https://jersey.github.io) client

```
target(baseUrl)
.property(ClientProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 1000)
.property(ClientProperties.READ_TIMEOUT, 1000)
```

And produces `java.net.SocketTimeoutException`, if the external server fails to respond within the set time.

For, [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/) client, I have tested below snippet and it works for read timeouts. And, this is the official [reference](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-client-api.html). Search for the parameters used in the below snippet in that page.

**Note**: For the versions from when this was supported, check this [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-6353).

```
target(baseUrl)
.property("http.connection.timeout", 5000)
.property("http.receive.timeout", 5000)
```

**Update** : *Below content may not be required by OP, but retaining for academics sake.* .

My hunch is, you are after a different goal. It seems to me that your external system is actually responding, but maybe at a rate slower than you would desire OR the response itself is bigger which in turn takes a longer time to consume than you desire?

In such cases, you may tune the timeout parameters. But, they work on a recurrent socket read basis. So, consider that you set the timeout to `X` and your response data is `Y` bytes. A slow read may mean that a socket.read() call is coming out with data but the content is 1/2 bytes. `X` applies to each read. So the full read may, in theory take `X*Y` ms.

If above is indeed your issue, then you may have to solve this using an external timekeeper. For example, you can:

1. Make the external service call via [ExecutorService.submit(Callable< T> task)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit-java.util.concurrent.Callable-)
2. And then, call resulting [Future.get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-)

Comment: It seems the client timeouts are not effected, but the class itself is not from a jersey package but `org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.spec.ClientImpl`. Also 'http.connect.timeout' doesn't work.

Comment: those properties seem to be ignored entirely as well

Comment: Sorry friend. These props should work and are working for me in a normal springboot app with `org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-rs-client:3.1.11`. I tested by setting the timeouts as described and pointing the url to `http://localhost:port` and using `nc -l port` to have a dummy listener, that doesn't respond. Perhaps you could try this once to figure out whether the problem you are facing is socket timeout not working or something else.

Comment: That comment helped me. On apache cxf 3.0.0 those http timeouts are ignored, but after updating tot 3.1.11 (because that was working for you) SocketTimeOut is thrown. Thank you so much

Comment: Glad to help. This has the fix versions: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-6353. Updated in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `server.connection-timeout`, but that will set a timeout to all requests, not only the ones made to the *external system*.

> **server.connection-timeout=** # Time that connectors wait for another HTTP request before closing the
>   connection. When not set, the connector's container-specific default
>   is used. Use a value of -1 to indicate no (that is, an infinite)
>   timeout.

[Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)

Comment: Requests to our system may take longer than the timeout used requesting the external system's data. So that is not really an option